# Website relaunch: Rewrite for old "?id=123" URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

After a website relaunch I need a mod_rewrite solution to prevent "page not found" errors. The old version of the website was operating with URLs like this:

```
http://domain-name.tld/index.php?id=123
```

I would like to have a Rewrite Rule that works with a pattern like this:

> "http://" or "https://" + "domain-name.tld" + * + "id=" + number  ->  "http://" or "https://" + "domain-name.tld" + document root + status code "301"

Since I'm not experienced in mod_rewrite and haven't found a similar example I would be grateful for every hint!

---

edit:

My provisional solution is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name\.tld [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain-name.tld/? [R=301,L]
```

This works so far, but ideally I´d like to keep the protocol (http/ https) variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store whether connection is secure or not like follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name\.tld [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)| [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http%1://domain-name.tld/? [R=301,L]
```